# Can Xcode 7 UI Testing be used for app file alone, without its code?

Tags: ios, xcode, terminal, xcode-ui-testing

I have a few app/ipa files. Using instruments ui automation i could perform actions using a js file and a terminal command. Did nt need the code/project of app file. But from Xcode 7 onwards UI Automation is deprecated. And apple have brought in UI testing. With the limited tutorials available in internet I could understand that UI testing can be implemented only on an Xcode project. It cannot be run in an pp file individually. Please do correct me if my understanding is wrong. And guide me on how to do it.
Thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

Don't know exactly how you can write UI testing for `APP`/`IPA` files.

But in the sense of code needed, I would rather say no. As the UI testing uses view hierarchy to find the UI Elements and perform actions, e.g. `app.buttons["Hi"].tap()`.